# Issues communicating to a provides using jax-ws

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservice-client

I have generated a jax-was client webservice classes and was trying to send a request to a remote webservice on https and got the error below.

The same webservice was working locally and on a dev server, but it's not working from the test server.  Any help would be appreciated

```
instance of an object.
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1310)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1036)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:591)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:532)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:470)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:185)
        com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget.executeCommand(ECCommandTarget.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.command.CommandCache.executeCommand(CommandCache.java:332)
    at com.ibm.websphere.command.CacheableCommandImpl.execute(CacheableCommandImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.AbstractECTargetableCommand.execute(AbstractECTargetableCommand.java:232)
    at com.sonepar.order.SoneparShippingBillingCheckoutCmdImpl.performExecute(SoneparShippingBillingCheckoutCmdImpl.java:259)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget.executeCommand(ECCommandTarget.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.command.CommandCache.executeCommand(CommandCache.java:332)
    at com.ibm.websphere.command.CacheableCommandImpl.execute(CacheableCommandImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.AbstractECTargetableCommand.execute(AbstractECTargetableCommand.java:232)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.BaseComponentImpl.executeCommand(BaseComponentImpl.java:202)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.WebAdapterComponentImpl.executeCommand(WebAdapterComponentImpl.java:46)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objimpl.WebAdapterServiceBeanBase.executeCommand(WebAdapterServiceBeanBase.java:58)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objects.EJSLocalStatelessWebAdapterService_ce749a4a.executeCommand(EJSLocalStatelessWebAdapterService_ce749a4a.java:31)
```